# Using jQuery selectable within an iFrame

Tags: jquery-ui, iframe

Im developing an HTML generator using jQuery through a drag & drop interface. Currently the user drags "block" elements onto an invisible div overlaying an iFrame (so that it appears to be dropping onto the iframe). When the element is dropped on this invisible div, the corresponding HTML is appended to the iFrame body.

Next, i want to give the user the ability to select an element in the iFrame, and change the properties of the selected element.

I have appended CSS imports and the jQuery/jQueryUI scripts into the iFrame head.

The issue I am facing is when the appended iFrame element is clicked, the jQuery select lasso only appears when the mouse leaves the iFrame, and on it appears outside of the iframe.

The reason I am using the iFrame is so when the code is "generated" for the user, i can just append the iFrame body content to a dialog box.

Has anyone faced issues with the iFrame and jQuery before? and is there any documentation/javaScript library that can assist me in this process?

Thanks!

Rory

Answer (score 0):

The "fix" around this issue is convoluted, but works in my situation.

I created a click event on each added element in the iframe like so:

```
$('iframe').contents().find('.elem'+blockVal).on('click', function(){
    $('iframe').contents().find('.selected').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
//alert('you have selected the block with class element'+ blockVal);
});
```

blockVal is a variable passed in from the function that appends the html to the iframe. The above function just adds a click listener to each element appended to the iframe. When any of the elements are clicked, they are given a class of 'selected', and any other element that already has that class, loses it.

Im sorry if that doesn't make any sense.

My advice to anyone doing something similar: Don't use an iframe.